# Using LoadLevel has effect on light

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a simple orthographic game in Unity, where the player has to shove a puzzle to open a door leading to the next room. The problem is, that when I enter the door, and the next scene is loaded using `LoadLevel()`, the light gets darker than it would normally be. This does not happen if I edit the scene inside Unity and start testing from there. I am wondering what happens, and how to fix it. I have even made a prefab of the Directional Light that lights up the scene to make sure they are equal, but that has no effect. How do I fix this?

Comment: **"This does not happen if I enter the scene directly inside Unity."** What does that mean?

Comment: Lighting in Unity includes two things: scene render settings on one hand and light objects that you position inside it on another. Which one are you referring to when you say "light gets darker"?

Comment: @Programmer I think OP means when he opens the scene file in Unity editor

Comment: @Programmer I will edit now to make it understandable. Thank you for asking. I am not good at making questions understandable :-{D

Comment: What scene lighting settings do you have in both scenes? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html

Comment: @MaxYankov I have not thanged any lighting settings yet.

Comment: @MaxYankov Oh ok. OP, please upload a screenshot of the scene with the good lighting and another screenshot  of the scene with bad lighting. Perhaps, a picture of your Directional light setting Maybe this will shed some lights on what's going on.

Comment: @Programmer How do i take screenshots inside Unity?

Comment: On Windows 10, use the snipping tools which is built it. Look at my answer. That's likely your problem. Not sure but if that does not solve your problem, then provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. It happens in the Editor **only** and also when **Continuous Baking** is enabled. This will not be present when you build your project.

To fix this in the Editor,  *Window* -> *Lighting* -> *Lightmap* Tab -> *Disable Continuous Baking* then click on the Build button to bake the lighting.

If using Unity 5.4, the settings changed a little bit *Window* -> *Lighting* -> *Lightmap* Tab -> uncheck ***Auto*** checkbox. Click on the Build button to bake the lighting.

If you move, remove or add objects in the Editor, you must rebake/build lightmaps again.

**EDIT**:

This has been renamed to Auto-Generate. See duplicate for new answer. This answer will remain for older version of Unity.