# Objects in Scene dark after calling LoadScene/LoadLevel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I completed Unity's roll-a-ball tutorial and it works fine. I changed a couple of materials to make it look better. I also added a C# script that should restart the level when the player falls off of the ground (I disables the walls). I am using Unity 5.5.

It initially looks like this: [image: Screenshot of Initial Level]

But when I go off the edge and the level restarts, it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of Reloaded Level]
It sometimes looks like this for a few seconds after opening unity when the editor is loading.

Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DeathTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: The first thing that comes in my mind is that their might be a problem with the ligth(s). Are you moving the lights on play? If so, are you positionning it well when the levels restarts? (when you mean restart, it means that the ball gets to it's original position, or you reaload the entire sceneN)

Comment: I am not moving the lights as far as I am aware. The entire scene restarts with the line `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The colors and materials are loaded. This is a lighting problem because lighliting is still calculating in the background. This will likely occur in the Editor *only*. This should *not* happen in the build.

Depending on your Unity version, you can fix this by going to *Windows* --> *Lighting* --> *Settings* then go to the *Scene* tab. Scroll down and disable *Auto Generate* checkbox then click the *Generate Lightning* button.

[image]

For older version of Unity with no *Auto Generate* checkbox, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813472/3785314).

Answer (score 9):

After play with Lighting tools, only one thing should be change on Lighting Setting for every scene.

1. Window > Rendering > Lighting (Unity 2020)
2. Click at Environment Tab
3. At Environment Lighting, change Source from Skybox to Color.
4. Select white color from Ambient Color.
5. Done. Try test it.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me at first, but then I realized that it's not a global setting and you have to be switched over to the correct scene. After changing to the correct scene, this worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found many solutions online but I was missing out a step, so I hope this helps.

Most solutions indicated to go to Windows->Lightning, then untick Auto and Click Generate Lighting. My problem was that while I was pressing the generate button I did not have all of my scenes loaded for preview (at least not the scene I had problems with), so it was only applying light generation to the loaded scenes. Make sure all scenes are loaded when generating the lights.

Answer (score 2):

Try Clearing Baked Data if you are using unity version around 5.5
Go to `Windows->Lightning->Untick Auto->Now Click dropdown arrow of Build Button which is near Auto(Check Box) -> Select Clear Baked Data`.
Now try Your code which looks fine although `SceneManager.LoadScene (1);` is enough.

Also unloading the previous scene and setting new scene as active scene is a good practice.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

File > Build settings > player Settings > (on the left) Graphics > (Top-Right) gear icon > Reset

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie and none of the advice on web helped me. However when I went to Window > Rendering > Lightning > scene tab; If "lightning setting" says “none”, click on it and choose “demo”- setting. Press “generate”.
So it seems like it was missing settings all together which made the scene go dark when loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same problem. What worked for me was to set `Directional Light > Light > Mode` to **Realtime**. (it was **Baked**, for some reason)

I hope this can help someone in the future.