# Scene gets darker after redirection Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, settings, assets

When I redirect from one scene to another, the second one gets darker. I tried changing continuous baking Window -> Lighting -> Lightmap Tab -> Disable Continuous Baking -> Press Build. But I can't find such setting in my version of Unity 2017.1. Also, Lighting --> Scene (Tab) --> Lightmapping Settings (Section) --> uncheck "Auto Generate" did not work it has made all my scenes go dark while running. So how can I fix this lighting problem?
I would be grateful for any help!

EDIT!!!
My scenes when Auto-Generate is checked:
[image]
[image]

My scenes when I uncheck Auto-Generate get dark when I build the scenes and even without building them:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your third sentence should [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447869/objects-in-scene-dark-after-calling-loadscene-loadlevel/42448608#42448608) your issue. Do you mind adding screenshot of before and after you load new scene? Also restart Unity to see if that fixes your problem

Comment: @Programmer even after I restart Unity all the scenes go dark

Comment: After unchecking "Auto Generate" checkbox, you **must**  click the "Generate Lightning" button. Did you do this part? Please do that. If you have, do it again. That should fix your issue.

Comment: I did that after clicking Auto Generate. I have already posted the results of this action

Comment: You have to do that for reach scene in in your project. Open the main scene, do that. Open the next scene do that. Do it for all of them then try to play again.

Comment: @Programmer I did that, and they still get dark

Comment: What happens when you build the game? If you build it to exe file and run it, is the problem there too?

Comment: When I uncheck Auto Generate and run the game, both scenes get dark. This effect persists even after the game is not running. I didn't build it to exe file

Comment: After unchecking "Auto Generate" checkbox, you must click the "Generate Lightning" button. Build as exe and run it. Tell me what happens in that build

Comment: In that build my first scene goes dark, and when I redirect to another scene it's already dark